# How to check when the app is killed in android nougat?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I wanted to know if my app is killed when it is in background. I am using android nougat device to test. But when I killed my app by swiping, onTaskRemoved() of my service is not calling.

Is there any way to know when the user kills the app before onDestroy() of the activity called?

Comment: When the app is in background and that is killed by OS due to low memory, OS kills the app and onDestroy is called of the app. And as far as my knowledge regarding life cycle is concerned, by swipping the app for killing the app no callback method is called.

Comment: no, if your entire process is killed, none but the assassin knows that

Comment: @AbdulWaheed `android.app.Application` does not have `onDestroy` method

Comment: @pskink yeah I know this I am keeping this thing in mind that if the app is in background some activity must be loaded in memory of process. And that activitiy's onDestroy will be called. Isn't it right?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed no, `Activity#onDestroy` docs say: `"Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!  [...] There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away."`

Comment: If activity destroyed I wanted to call api. I thought of calling that api in onDestroy of activity. In case app is killed by swiping how can I call api? I am not getting any idea to solve this situation problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onTaskRemoved()` method is only called when you have set `android:stopWithTask="false"` in your manifest file.

So do check your manifest file because whenever the service is killed by the system then `onTaskRemoved()` is always called.

Comment: I tried stopWithTask false. Some times onTaskRemoved() is calling. but not all the time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on when it is being called and when it is not?

Comment: Actually I was testing with Xiaomi redmi note4 device. Before i dint enable auto start activity in security. So this onTaskRemoved() was not calling. Now its working fine.